# Where to keep a session information in Java WS

Tags: java, web-services, encryption

I am building a secure system, that must be sure, that the user sending it messages is the same that received an access key. Example.

User Bob, has a property `uniqueCode`, that is unique just to him, and would enable him to receive various information from the server.

There is a web service, that has various methods for returning various sensitive data. When a client the user is using first connects to the web service, it does so via authenticate method, that

1. generates a pseudo random key for this user
2. saves that key on the server and returns it to the user.

Each subsequent request from the client to the WS requires the `uniqueCode` and the key. If the pair is valid, the request returns the needed information. If there has been no activity for x minutes, the key is invalidated, and the client asks the user to log in again.

Now my question is, how to store the key on the server? The key would be a Java object, that could be serialized.

My options

- Keep them in a session. This is what a senior programmer at the company suggested, but that doesn't seem to be the way to go. Everywhere I read, the suggest that WS should not rely on underlying HTTP sessions.
- Keep them in a database. A possible solution, but that would require me to create a specific database, adding a whole another level to the problem.
- Keep them in binary encrypted files. This one seems the way to go, but is it? Since I would generate a key upon login, I could save the key+some info in a binary file, encrypt it by itself, and the pass it to the user. If the key I receive back can decipher the users file, and the information is correct, return the information the user requested.

Is my thinking correct, or am I missing something? I reckon that the last one would be the safest way to go, since if someone gains access to my system, breaking into db would be easy, but deciphering a file without knowing another users key would be quite tough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to persist the the key, so that it is available after server restart?

If yes, then you do have to go with keeping the keys in database, or on the file system, or some other mechanism that works for you. I would go with the database - that way you don't rely on the filesystem in case you move your application, change permissions, etc.

If no, why not just use some cache with Time To Live inside your app? Just use `uniqueCode` as key, and the encryption key as value. Popular options would be:

- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)
- [Guava Caches](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)
- If you don't mind cleaning old sessions manually on time, a plain old `HashMap` could do.

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable, and would contribute to higher usability. On a sidenote, if the key I need to keep is an object, how do I store that in a MySQL db? Serialize it, crypt it, and then store as a blob?

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks If the key has some textual form, you could use it instead of serialization and blob, that would be much easier to work with. As for encryption, thats up to you - do it if you are afraid that someone might compromise your database - but at that point you would have bigger worries than user sessions anyway.

Comment: Went ahead, and implemented the Database version, with a periodic clean. Thanks!